# Is it possible to train two neural networks combined with same output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, train

Say I have two kinds of input that I want my neural network to learn a possible from:

- one 2D image
- some 1D metadata about the image

This case and similar cases seem problematic to me because the two input data isn't easily put in the same input tensor due to their potentially different shapes and sizes. I gather it could require convolutional layers for the 2D-image but only fully connected layers for the metadata.

I would like to train one network to learn from both these inputs simultaneously. Is this possible, or what is the standard approach to this kind of problem? (I've tried to illustrate the idea below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely possible. For instance, you can look into Siamese network.

However you will have to most likely recode a custom architecture and a custom loss fonction, if your problem is not a "classic" one.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understood the mathematical description on the wikipedia page, but I think the section about "half-twin" networks describes my case, and I tried it out in pytorch and got it to work after several practical caveats (mostly torchsummary that didn't support different sized inputs). "Half-twin" networks was very difficult to find when googling. Good search terms for practical examples was something like "pytorch multiple inputs" or "multiple input arguments".